# print a variable using another

Tags: bash, echo

I have my script setup like this, i want to print switch names using loop.

```
swn1="something"
swn2="somethingelse"

for (( i=1; i<="$ii"; i++ ))
    do              
       echo "$swn$i "
    done
```

I have searched and searched but no luck, can anyone help me how to print swn using for loop ?

Comment: improve formatting of code please

Comment: Okay i will but can you help me please !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want an array...

```
swn=("something" "something else")

for i in "${swn[@]}"
do
    echo $i
done
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution for that is variable indirection.

```
swn1="something"
swn2="somethingelse"

for (( i=1; i<="$ii"; i++ ))
    do              
        var="swn$i"
        echo "${!var}"
    done
```

Although normally you could solve your problem with arrays, but the way to print a variable using another is through it.

As explained in the bash manual:

> If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), a
>   level of variable indirection is introduced. Bash uses the value of
>   the variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of the
>   variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the
>   rest of the substitution, rather than the value of parameter itself.
>   This is known as indirect expansion. The exceptions to this are the
>   expansions of ${!prefix} and ${!name[@]}. The
>   exclamation point must immediately follow the left brace in order to
>   introduce indirection.

Comment: Tnx konsolebox, i should have used array in first place

I got it working like that

swn[1]="something"
swn[2]="somethingelse"

ii=2

for (( i=1; i<="$ii"; i++ ))
    do 
      echo "Switch: ${swn[$i]}"
    done

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. `swn1` is one token, `swn2` is another. It looks like you want an array, and if you want an array in a bash script you either want to process the values as separate lines in a file, or switch to using Perl.

Separate lines:

```
echo "something" > swnfile;
echo "somethingelse" >> swnfile;
cat file | while read line; do
    echo "$line";
done
```